# Working across multiple workbooks/instances 1004 error

Tags: vba, copy, instances

I am getting a Run-time error '1004': Method 'Ranger' of object '_Worksheet' failed on the following code.

```
Public sh2 As Worksheet
Public sh1 As Worksheet
Public wb1 As Workbook
Public OtherWB As Object

Sub Test()

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set OtherWB = GetObject("C:\OtherWB.xlsm")
Set sh1 = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sh2 = OtherWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

sh2.Range("A7").Select
sh2.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)).Copy
sh1.Range("c8").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

End Sub
```

Basically I want to copy from OtherWB.xlsm which is already opened in another instance of Excel and paste it to the current workbook.  The 2nd instance is necessary here as the system uses multiple monitors.  I can pull cell data no problem with other properties but when it comes to using "Copy", things go a bit haywire.  Is Copy not a permissible property when using Excel woorkbooks as objects?

Comment: in what line have you got an error?

Comment: sh2.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)).Copy   It lets me select the cell.

Comment: Read [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/905164). Maybe it could help

Comment: No it didn't.  Thanks though.

Comment: I got wierd results trying to copy between instances.  This did work though: `sh1.Range("c8").Resize(1, 3).Value = sh2.Range("B7").Resize(1, 3).Value`

Comment: Tim, that works except that it doesn't bring the formatting over which I would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the `ActiveCell` of a different workbook without specifying so.

Try :

```
With sh2
    .Range(.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), .ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)).Copy
End With
```

**EDIT:**

I didn't try the above code, in case it doesn't work, try to replace :

```
sh2.Range("A7").Select
sh2.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)).Copy
```

with :

```
sh2.Range(sh2.Range("A7").Offset(0, 1), sh2.Range("A7").Offset(0, 3)).Copy
```

**EDIT2 :**

Also note that the `.Copy` method has a `Destination` parameter, which can be in a different workbook. Read the [MSDN Range.Copy Method Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760.aspx).

Comment: sh2.Range(sh2.Range("A7").Offset(0, 1), sh2.Range("A7").Offset(0, 3)).Copy <----  We're getting closer.  This copied, but when I went to paste, it pasted it as a picture object onto the other workbook.

Comment: Try : sh2.Range(sh2.Range("A7").Offset(0, 1), sh2.Range("A7").Offset(0, 3)).Copy Destination:=sh1.Range("c8")

Comment: Copy method of range class failed.

Comment: Now that I look at it, it makes sense; the copied range is not the same size as the destination range. Try : sh2.Range(sh2.Range("A7").Offset(0, 1), sh2.Range("A7").Offset(0, 3)).Copy Destination:=sh1.Range(sh1.Range("C8"), sh1.Range("C10"))

Comment: Am headed home in not too long, will be able to check/test from there.

Comment: sh1.Range("C8").PasteSpecial xlClipboardFormatDspText, False  '''' I think I found her!! Thanks for all your help.